# SFDX: Deploy Source to Org : Error - SourcePathInvalid

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am Getting **SourcePathInvalid** for file path **c://projectpath//projectname/extension-output-#2** at deployment time.  Please refer attach image for more details.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because for the force:source:deploy command that path of the folder or the file you want to deploy is not correct.

Try opening up the file and doing a deploy or copy the file path or directory path by running pwd on your command terminal and manually type the command force:source:deploy --sourcepath "path of the directory or file"

Where path is the file path

Comment: Thanks Mohit for your response. I am doing full deployment from package.xml and getting invalid path error for file extension-output-#2 which is not present in workspace.

Comment: Hi Pramod .As I said ,do you have the path of the file .Are you on Windows or Mac ?

Comment: Hi Mohit, I am on Windows, i am not able to locate the file or folder with this name "extension-output-#2" for which i am getting invalid path error.

Comment: You know the path of the package.xml file ? All you need is to execute that in the terminal

Comment: I am new to VS code editor, i was trying to deploy by running the SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org command on package.xml. Through terminal now i am able to deploy the changes. thanks for your help Mohit.

Comment: @PramodSingh Please mark the answer or upvote if it helped you :)